# Ошибка TypeError python

Tags: python

Пытался реализовать передвижение в двухмерном мире pygame:

```
class Player(GameSprite):
keys = key.get_pressed
if keys[K_LEFT] and self.rect.x > 5:
      self.rect.x -= self.speed
if keys[K_RIGHT] and self.rect.x < win_width - 80:
      self.rect.x += self.speed
if keys[K_UP] and self.rect.y > 5:
      self.rect.y -= self.speed
if keys[K_DOWN] and self.rect.y < win_height - 80:
      self.rect.y += self.speed
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled-.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Player(GameSprite):
  File "Untitled-.py", line 29, in Player
    if keys[K_LEFT] and self.rect.x > 5:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Player(GameSprite):
    keys = key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT] and self.rect.x > 5:
          self.rect.x -= self.speed
    if keys[K_RIGHT] and self.rect.x < win_width - 80:
          self.rect.x += self.speed
    if keys[K_UP] and self.rect.y > 5:
          self.rect.y -= self.speed
    if keys[K_DOWN] and self.rect.y < win_height - 80:
          self.rect.y += self.speed
```